# Add array value dynamically with a specific index?

Tags: javascript, jquery, salesforce-lightning

```
createObjectDataadd: function(component, event) {
    var index = event.getParam("indexVar");
    console.log(index);

    var RowItemList1 = component.get("v.QuotelinitemList"); 
     RowItemList1.push({
        'sobjectType': 'Quote_Line_Item__c',
        'Name':'',
        'Client_P_N__c': ''
         });
     RowItemList1.splice(index+1,0,RowItemList1); 

    //  for (var i = index; i <RowItemList1.length; i++) { 
    //  RowItemList1.splice(index+1,0,rowli); 
    //    }              
    component.set("v.QuotelinitemList", RowItemList1);
    //RowItemList1.splice(index-1,0,RowItemList1); 
},
```

Quote_Line_Item__c is an object. suppose it has three records. Every record has index value. Every record has button new quote_line_item button which it is pushing a new quote line item record at end of the array.

My problem is it adding at the last index.I  want to add it on next index where the record new quote line item button is pressed.

I tried many ways but it is not coming.

Comment: `RowItemList1.push('sobjectType':...`  missing opening bracket `{`

Comment: @Heretic Monkey I tried those solution .I want to use array.push to specified index

Comment: @KarthikaRam You can't use `push` that way, so you have to use the methods described in the duplicate. If you've tried them, please describe your attempts, preferably as a [mcve] so that others can reproduce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For adding item at specified index in Array, you can use "[Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)" like below. It takes 3 arguments: index, number of items to remove from that index, new value(s) to add. So, trick is you can pass 0 as second argument which means you do not want to delete any item

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4]

function addItem(item, index) {
  arr.splice(index, 0, item)
}

addItem(10, 1)
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: I tried but it adding all three records

Comment: Can you pls show the code you tried Or exact data so that I can see what's going on..

Comment: I have updated my coding above please check .it is adding new quote line item to all records

Comment: There is one missing bracket in 
RowItemList1.push(
        'sobjectType': 'Quote_Line_Item__c',
        'Name':'',
        'Client_P_N__c': ''
         });

Comment: after push({... is this by chance or is this your issue. Pls check

Comment: No.Its not that issue